# Nearest point on line from a point in PostGIS and its attribute value

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, nearest-neighbor, knn

Consider the following image;
[image]

I have points (shown in blue circles) stored in my database with their geometry and an attribute value. Additionally, I have another table with User Points (yellow rhomboids). I want to get the projection of user points on the path line of the vehicle points on the basis of their proximity to path line and also on those project points on line, I want to interpolate the value of attribute values of the nearby vehicle points.

So far, I have been able to get the points as shown in yellow circle using `ST_ClosestPoint` but currently I am unable to proceed further to get the interpolated values of the attribute and assign it to the yellow circles.

Comment: Some combo of ST_LineInterpolatePoint, ST_LineLocatePoint and ST_ClosestPoint. To be honest I don't really understand the question, and to how the interpolation is supposed to work. And, they are rhomboids, not rectangles :-)

Comment: What part of the question are you unable to comprehend specifically? I want to get the values at the yellow circles with the help of its nearby blue circle values.

Comment: The arrows pointing down towards "interpolated points in vehicle path line" is very confusing. Based on what you have siad, you would seem to need ST_LineInterpolatePoint.

Comment: what @JohnPowellakaBarça said; `ST_LineLocatePoint` returns the fraction [0, 1] of linelength of the projected point (i.e. sort of one step further than `ST_ClosestPoint` and skipping the geometry creation), which you could use directly as percentage to interpolate between the two *Vehicle Points* attributes. wrap the nearest line search in a `LATERAL JOIN` query (i.e. *(K) Nearest Neighbor* (*KNN*).

Comment: do the edges have a reference attribute to link to both their connected *Vehicle Points*?

Comment: @ThingumaBob no these are just points from which I have constructed a line segment to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend on running this over and over, have possible other/future tasks that need edges to work with or those tables are very large, I recommend to create a properly indexed `edges` table with `src_id`&`trg_id` and `src_val`&`trg_val` (*ids* and *values*, name them as you like of course) of their connecting *Vehicle Points*. Using these columns, it will be easy to interpolate from one connected point's value to the other by getting a fraction of their value's difference.
I will assume you have those edges stored as such a table and with the above naming; running

```
SELECT up.id,
       edg.src_val + (edg.trg_val - edg.src_val) * ST_LineLocatePoint(edg.geom, up.geom) AS int_val,
       ST_ClosestPoint(edg.geom, up.geom) AS geom
FROM <user_points> AS up
JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT src_val,
         trg_val,
         geom
  FROM edges
  ORDER BY up.geom <-> geom
  LIMIT 1
) AS edg
ON true;
```

will return the `<user_points>.id`, the projected point `geom` on the closest edge of each point and the interpolated value `int_val` (interpolated based on the fraction of line length from the start at which the closest point was projected). Add `<user_points>` columns as you need in the outer query. 
Using the `<->` *KNN* operator, this will also make excellent use of the spatial index on both tables.

**Update:**
Based on your info, you can create the edge table with

```
CREATE TABLE edges AS
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
         edgs.*
  FROM (
    SELECT id AS src_id,
           LEAD(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS trg_id,
           val AS src_val,
           LEAD(val) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS trg_val,
           ST_MakeLine(geom, LEAD(geom) OVER(ORDER BY id)) AS geom
    FROM points_from_video
  ) AS edgs
  WHERE edgs.geom IS NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE edges ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX sidx_edges_geom
  ON edges
  USING GIST (geom);
```

Can't test right now, not 100% sure if `ST_MakeLine` returns `NULL` or throws an error if the last row is processed and no leading row was found. Give a shout if you encounter an error.

Comment: Troubling you again but could you please tell me how can I make edges table from vehicle points and its attribute value, call it val. ?

Comment: @raosaeedali yes and no; you seem to have done it, albeit *on-the-fly* I take it? how did you find pairs of points? one would e.g. need an attribute/sequence number to know which two points have to be connected, or some rules to do so...could you elaborate, then I'll happily edit my answer to include that step.

Comment: So far, I have been able to make projection of the points on the line using this;
SELECT ST_LineInterpolatePoint(foo.the_line, ST_LineLocatePoint(foo.the_line, ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(points_nearby_pathline.geom)))) as geom
FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine(location) the_line  FROM points_from_video ) As foo, points_nearby_pathline;

I don't know how can I store the attribute value from points_from_video in the newly projected points.

Comment: @raosaeedali so you are simply passing in all points and make one long linestring? I was under the impression you would create individual linestrings with two neighboring points. so your point data does not have any attribute to be used to identify a pair of points? since then, my answer is useless...

Comment: is there a way to make edges table using the points from another table?

Comment: basically, you can make that edge table with `CREATE TABLE edges AS (SELECT ST_MakeLine(location) AS the_line FROM points_from_video)`. this will create one (possibly random) linestring from those points, in order of their rows passed into `ST_MakeLine`.

Comment: I want edges to be created as individual linestrings as from two neighboring points as you've mentioned in one of your earlier comments.

Comment: okay. do your points have any order? is there any way to define which points are neighbors? otherwise, one could only find neighbors by spatial proximity, which could lead to unexpected results...

Comment: order: could we e.g. say point id 1&2 are a pair, 2&3 are a pair etc.?

Comment: Actually the points are in order with their ids. Starting from 1 till the last point in table.

Comment: @raosaeedali now *that* was the info I was looking for...,) I'll update my answer later to include the edge table creation query.

Comment: tried the updated query and it worked like a charm. Also, now I am able to perform the interpolation as per your first query. However could you please clarify that in the selection query 2nd line (edg.trg_val - src.src_val) you meant (edg.trg_val - edg.src_val) right?

Comment: **yes** - sorry, will be corrected